# Manage Groups page not showing parent groups with nesting of child groups after upgrade

Tags: groups

After upgrading to from 4.7.14 to 4.7.22 The layout of the Manage Groups page listing changed from:

Parent Group
-- Child 1
-- Child 2

Another Group

To:

Child 1 group
Child of: Parent Group
etc.

See attached picture for display

Is there a setting that controls how the nesting is displayed?

(There is also a database error when the page is first displayed and then the groups are displayed)

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature that needs to be changed.

Continued testing - see the second picture which shows the preferred layout.  the second layout resulted from using the browser back arrow and then the forward arrow.  Very strange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Database error - shows this in ConfigAndLog file: Expected one CustomField but found 0

Comment: This is very strange and repeatable.   Probably some kind of bug.  Will report on Jira as well after more testing.   Posting this in the event others think they are losing their minds as well!

Comment: similar problem here... however it looks slightly different: The little triangle in the "Manage Groups" Listing has been gone. While adding add a group to a contact the sub-groups are listed, management via "Manage Groups" is difficult as you have to know at least a part of the group description to use the "find" dialog.

Comment: I'm also dealing with this issue.  Don't see the arrows that should show the drop down of 'children' groups.  Instead all the groups are just listed.